# Working with styling in ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to implement CSS in reactjs, but from this url

[ReactJS - Animations](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_animations.htm)

**App.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = require('react-addons-css-transition-group');

    class App extends React.Component {
    
       render() {
          return (
             <div>
                <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName = "example"
                   transitionAppear = {true} transitionAppearTimeout = {500}
                   transitionEnter = {false} transitionLeave = {false}>
                        
                   <h1>My Element...</h1>
                </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
             </div>      
          );
       }
    }

export default App;
```

**css/style.css**

```
.example-appear {
   opacity: 0.01;
}

.example-appear.example-appear-active {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
}
```

I can't figure out `example-appear` and `example-appear.example-appear-active`in css? where they are used in **App.jsx**?

is there any resource available on net?? Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: why this post get negative remarks?

Comment: Probably because it's unclear, and off topic

Comment: @TimCastelijns but I have define every thing? so how it become off topic?

Comment: *I have define every thing* really? Your question is basically: "i want to implement something", "here is a link, i dont understand it", "how do i do this", "are there resources available"

Comment: @TimCastelijns thanks, yeah u are right.

Answer (score 2):

You apply styles with React almost exactly as you would normally. The difference is if you're using `jsx` syntax, you type `className` instead of just `class`.

For example, if you have a component like this:

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        Hello, world! I am a CommentBox.
      </div>
    );
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(
  <CommentBox />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

and a css file with this:

```
.commentBox {
  color: red;
}
```

Then your text will be red.

I suggest you get started with a nice walkthrough of the whole process including using webpack (which is how you would bundle and include the actual CSS in your page). This is what I started with and thought it was great: http://survivejs.com/webpack/introduction/

Comment: but what the above URL is used for CSS, I can't find any classname attribute their?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question.